# smooth scrolling on Safari 15.4 breaks scrolling entirely

Tags: css, safari, smooth-scrolling

I have a div with style `overflow:hidden` and `white-space:nowrap`. Then a button that scrolls the div left via `scrollLeft += 50`. Works fine until I add `scroll-behavior:smooth` to the CSS of the div. Then it doesn't scroll at all in Safari 15.4. On all other browsers I have tested it works fine. Some ignore the smooth scrolling but it doesn't break the scrolling. In Safari it breaks the scrolling. I have setup a simple test page for this error [scrolling test](https://www.lybrary.com/test_scroll.html). What am I doing wrong? If this is a bug in Safari any ideas for workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug as of Safari 15.4.

Previously, it didn't support smooth scrolling and would scroll instantly. Since the new update, they have introduced an incomplete version of smooth scrolling, the scrollbar is required to be visible for it to work.

The current workarounds are to either use a scrolling library, making your own version/polyfill or checking useragent and give it a version without smooth scrolling if it's Safari.

WebKit Bugzilla Link: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238497